# combining pages

Tags: spacing

I am trying to put the contents of the \listoftables command (defined below) on the same page as the last page of the \listoffigures command (also defined below).  In other words, I do not want a newpage or page skip between the two commands.  This is someone elses template, and I do not understand it fully -- I tried deleting \newpage between the \listoffigures and \listoftables command, but it does not compile.

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \@chapteronefalse
    \if@arabic\relax\else\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}\fi
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapteruaf*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\uppercase{\listfigurename}}%
              {\uppercase{\listfigurename}}}%
    \@chapteronetrue
    %% get this in contents as a section
    \addcontentsline{toc}{frontchapter}{\listfigurename}
    %\cftafterloftitle
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    %\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}

\newcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \@chapteronefalse
    \if@arabic\relax\else\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}\fi
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapteruaf*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{\uppercase{\listtablename}}{\uppercase{\listtablename}}}%
    %% get this in contents as a section
    \@chapteronetrue
    \addcontentsline{toc}{frontchapter}{\listtablename}
    %\cftafterloftitle
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

Comment: A wild guess, based on how the standard LaTeX classes work, is that the new page comes from the chapter command (`\chpteruaf`). But is no less than impossible to say without a *complete* **and** *working* example. Please edit your question to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, if "it's someone else's template and you don't understand it fully", you should have a *really* good reason to use it, otherwise you'll have more problems trying to use the template than building one from scratch.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the template?

Comment: Hi @Werner, sorry for the delayed reply I could not find it before. it is at the top of the page of https://glaciers.gi.alaska.edu/pubs/theses  .  I am finding it difficult to come up with a MWE because it seems there are lots of things connected in the template, and I am not sure what is all needed to compile. I do not have the time to learn everything I need at the moment to make something this complicated from scratch as I think it would take several weeks!